# Touch Bar no longer working in Chrome

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, google-chrome, touch-bar

### Data

- Brand new Macbook Pro 13.3" running macOS Sierra
- New install of Chrome
- No Touch Bar settings ever modified

### Problem

Initially, Chrome would show custom touch bar icons. Like full-colour previews of each tab to switch between them. WhatsApp Web would have text auto prediction.

Suddenly, this isn't showing at all. In fact, in Chrome, there are *no* icons in the Touch Bar whatsoever, just the Escape key.

### Question

Since then, I've tried playing with the Touch Bar settings and reinstalling Chrome, but nothing's made a difference. **Any ideas how to get it back again?**

Comment: reinstall the operating system would probably fix it assuming it is not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** I'm an idiot

**Real answer:** This was never a Chome feature, *it's a Safari feature*.

I was simply confused as I had to use Safari when trying it out in the Apple Store. Obviously, native Apple apps have more Touch Bar integration but I'm still surprised there's nothing on Chrome and even Canary doesn't have much.

I'm still seeing strange behaviour where in some folders in Finder the delete icon doesn't appear and in some it does, but this question was actually user error.

Answer (score 2):

The first things I would do are reset your NVRAM followed by resetting your SMC. See below for further info.

**Resetting the NVRAM on Late-2016 MacBook Pro models**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). To reset the NVRAM on all Late-2016 MacBook Pro models (with and without Touch Bar) follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note 1:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Note 2:** These steps will also work to reset the NVRAM (or PRAM) for all Macs. However, the late-2016 MBP models actually required the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys to be held down for 20 seconds, while earlier Macs did not *require* this, but doing so does not cause any problems either.

**Reset the SMC**

Your MacBook Pro has a system management controller that can easily be reset. To do this on your particular model, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Let me know how you go after doing both resets.

Comment: I'm a little confused why this would help. The Touch Bar works fine in all other apps. Nevertheless, it made no difference.

Comment: My apologies - I interpreted _WhatsApp Web would have text auto prediction_ as indicating that WhatsApp no longer did this after initially doing so, hence why I thought it was an issue with at least two apps. What exact version of Google Chrome are you running?

Comment: I just updated to the latest -  57.0.2987.98 (64-bit).

Using Canary I get Touch Bar icons but they are not customisable and there is no way to switch between tabs.

What is the correct Touch Bar behaviour for Chrome?